# Why app is crashing while trying to load my nib file?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to load xib within a view but I don't know it's throwing run time error as **"Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x7fff86f664a0) to 'SlideDemo.Plan' (0x1087e0000)."**
The xib is a view. I have also defined Plan class in my xib owner's file.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var topView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let abc = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Plan", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Plan
        topView.addSubview(abc)
        
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class Plan: UIView {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set class name for the xib file to `Plan`

[image]

Comment: in file owener? already given

Comment: the check box  below class name field  > inherit module from target checked ??

Comment: thanks but, when we define the class name in file owners?

Comment: see edit............

Comment: @Sh_Khan shouldn't you set the class in **File's Owner**?

Comment: @aheze added correct steps in photo

Comment: @Sh_Khan huh I always put the class after selecting Placeholders -> File's Owner, not the view.